# Why can I not see my h1 heading at the top of my page?

Tags: html, css

I have added a h1 heading at the top of a few of my pages on my website but they do not appear at I run when I run it. Below I have my HTML for one of the pages, a screen shot of the page, as well as my CSS. It is supposed to go below the nav bar before the content of the page and be centered. [image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>complete responsive coffee shop website design</title>

    <!-- font awesome cdn link  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">

    <!-- custom css file link  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    
<!-- header section starts  -->

<header class="header">

    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
    </a>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        <a href="products.html">Products</a>
        <a href="review.html">Review</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <a href="blogs.html">Blogs</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="icons">
        <div class="fas fa-search" id="search-btn"></div>
        <div class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart-btn"></div>
        <div class="fas fa-bars" id="menu-btn"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="search-form">
        <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="search here...">
        <label for="search-box" class="fas fa-search"></label>
    </div>

    <div class="cart-items-container">
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/MapleBacon-Front_900x.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Maple Bacon 12oz</h3>
                <div class="price">$14.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/jackedolantern-front_540x.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Jacked O Lantern 12oz</h3>
                <div class="price">$14.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/HighVoltage-Front_540x.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>High Voltage 12oz</h3>
                <div class="price">$14.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-item">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
            <img src="images/MediumRoast-Front_540x.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Medium Roast 12oz</h3>
                <div class="price">$14.99/-</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Checkout Now</a>
    </div>

</header>

<!-- header section ends -->

<!-- about section starts  -->

<section class="about" id="about">

    <h1 class="heading"> <span>about</span> us </h1>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="image">
            <img src="images/coffee-bar.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h3>What makes our coffee special?</h3>
            <p>The difference between specialty and “regular” coffee lies mainly in the quality of coffee beans. Not all coffee beans are created equal. In fact, according to the pyramid of coffee bean quality, they can be divided into three main categories.</p>
            <p>Specialty coffee is also defined by roasting and brewing. Specialty coffee baristas know that the wrong coffee-water ratio, temperature, or brewing time can blend and ultimately ruin the unique aromas.
                ‘The task of the barista is to know how to extract the flavors,’. ‘Every morning, we at Daydream Cafe. first set the grinder, depending on how coarse we want the coffee to be. Then we check the water temperature — the lower the temperature, the less coffee extraction. We don’t want coffee that’s too strong because that would give it a bitter taste, but also not one that is too weak because then its flavor won’t be distinct enough. The same can be said about the brewing time. A lot of precision also goes into weighing the coffee. We have to use the exact amount needed — one gram too much or too little and the flavor is lost.’</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>

<!-- about section ends -->

<!-- footer section starts  -->

<section class="footer">

    <div class="share">
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-f"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-linkedin"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fab fa-pinterest"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        <a href="products.html">Products</a>
        <a href="review.html">Review</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        <a href="blogs.html">Blogs</a>
    </div>

    <div class="credit">Created by <span>Landon Byrd</span> | 2021 All Rights Reserved</div>

</section>

<!-- footer section ends -->

















<!-- custom js file link  -->
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

:root{
    --main-color:#d3ad7f;
    --black:#13131a;
    --bg:#010103;
    --border:.1rem solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

*{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none; border:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .2s linear;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-padding-top: 9rem;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: .8rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: transparent;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5rem;
}

body{
    background: var(--bg);
}

section{
    padding:2rem 7%;
}

.heading{
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.heading span{
    color:var(--main-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn{
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:.9rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color:#fff;
    background: var(--main-color);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover{
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

.header{
    background: #45230f;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding:1.5rem 7%;
    border-bottom: var(--border);
    position: fixed;
    top:0; left: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header .logo img{
    height: 6rem;
}

.header .navbar a{
    margin:0 1rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.header .navbar a:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
    border-bottom: .1rem solid var(--main-color);
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.header .icons div{
    color:#204d48;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

.header .icons div:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

#menu-btn{
    display: none;
}

.header .search-form{
    position: absolute;
    top:115%; right: 7%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
}

.header .search-form.active{
    transform: scaleY(1);
}

.header .search-form input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:var(--black);
    padding:1rem;
    text-transform: none;
}

.header .search-form label{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    color:var(--black);
}

.header .search-form label:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.header .cart-items-container{
    position: absolute;
    top:100%; right: -100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
    width: 35rem;
    background: #fff;
    padding:0 1.5rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container.active{
    right: 0;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item{
    position: relative;
    margin:2rem 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .fa-times{
    position: absolute;
    top:1rem; right: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--black);
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .fa-times:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item img{
    height: 7rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .content h3{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:var(--black);
    padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.header .cart-items-container .cart-item .content .price{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.header .cart-items-container .btn{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.home{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:url(../images/home-img.jpeg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.home .content{
    max-width: 60rem;
}

.home .content h3{
    font-size: 6rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
}

.home .content p{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 1.8;
    padding:1rem 0;
    color:#eee;
}

.about .row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background:var(--black);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.about .row .image{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
}

.about .row .image img{
    width: 100%;
}
.about .row .content{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
    padding:2rem;
}

.about .row .content h3{
    font-size: 3rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.about .row .content p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:1rem 0;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

.menu .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.menu .box-container .box{
    padding:5rem;
    text-align: center;
    border:var(--border);    
}

.menu .box-container .box img{
    height: 10rem;
}

.menu .box-container .box h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding:1rem 0;
}

.menu .box-container .box .price{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding:.5rem 0;
}

.menu .box-container .box .price span{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.menu .box-container .box:hover{
    background:#fff;
}

.menu .box-container .box:hover > *{
    color:var(--black);
}

.products .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box{
    text-align: center;
    border:var(--border);
    padding: 2rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .icons a{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border:var(--border);
    color:#fff;
    margin:.3rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .icons a:hover{
    background:var(--main-color);
}

.products .box-container .box .image{
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.products .box-container .box .image img{
    height: 25rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content h3{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content .stars{
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content .stars i{
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: var(--main-color);
}

.products .box-container .box .content .price{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.products .box-container .box .content .price span{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.review .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.review .box-container .box{
    border:var(--border);
    text-align: center;
    padding:3rem 2rem;
}

.review .box-container .box p{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:2rem 0;
}

.review .box-container .box .user{
    height: 7rem;
    width: 7rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.review .box-container .box h3{
    padding:1rem 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.review .box-container .box .stars i{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.contact .row{
    display: flex;
    background:var(--black);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap:1rem;
}

.contact .row .map{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.contact .row form{
    flex:1 1 45rem;
    padding:5rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact .row form h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color:#fff;
}

.contact .row form .inputBox{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    background:var(--bg);
    border:var(--border);
}

.contact .row form .inputBox span{
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.contact .row form .inputBox input{
    width: 100%;
    padding:2rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: none;
    background:none;
}

.blogs .box-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap:1.5rem;
}

.blogs .box-container .box{
    border:var(--border);    
}

.blogs .box-container .box .image{
    height: 25rem;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .image img{
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}

.blogs .box-container .box:hover .image img{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content{
    padding:2rem;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content .title{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color:#fff;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content .title:hover{
    color:var(--main-color);
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content span{
    color:var(--main-color);
    display: block;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.blogs .box-container .box .content p{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color:#ccc;
    padding:1rem 0;
}

.footer{
    background:#45230f;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer .share{
    padding:1rem 0;
}

.footer .share a{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:#fff;
    border:var(--border);
    margin:.3rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.footer .share a:hover{
    background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.footer .links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding:2rem 0;
    gap:1rem;
}

.footer .links a{
    padding:.7rem 2rem;
    color:#fff;
    border:var(--border);
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer .links a:hover{
    background:var(--main-color);
}

.footer .credit{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    padding:1.5rem;
}

.footer .credit span{
    color:var(--main-color);
}


/* media queries  */
@media (max-width:991px){

    html{
        font-size: 55%;
    }

    .header{
        padding:1.5rem 2rem;
    }

    section{
        padding:2rem;
    }

}

@media (max-width:768px){

    #menu-btn{
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .header .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top:100%; right: -100%;
        background: #fff;
        width: 30rem;
        height: calc(100vh - 9.5rem);
    }

    .header .navbar.active{
        right:0;
    }

    .header .navbar a{
        color:var(--black);
        display: block;
        margin:1.5rem;
        padding:.5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    .header .search-form{
        width: 90%;
        right: 2rem;
    }

    .home{
        background-position: left;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .home .content h3{
        font-size: 4.5rem;
    }

    .home .content p{
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }

}

@media (max-width:450px){

    html{
        font-size: 50%;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Well it gets hidden by the header element you fixed positioned there, doesn't it?

Comment: [Code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. Please edit out irrelevant parts. You can also turn the sample code into a live example using the [snippets feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/90527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your style file

before

```
.heading{
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
}
```

After

```
.heading{
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Had to set my margin to 10 and set the font to 4.

Comment: While this code may be useful to the OP, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how it works, and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.